# MVVM in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, mvvm

I am confused about using MVVM in ASP.NET MVC.

Views in ASP.NET MVC can only take in one Model class. I have a view and controller that needs to operate on data from more than one model class, so I created a ViewModel class that contains instances of these model classes.

I could populate the ViewModel in the Controller, but I have heard people say that you should keep your controllers thin. So I have created a service class to populate the viewmodel. This service class is then injected into the controller.

1) Is this the right way of going about things doing MVVM in MVC? Can people point me to some resources about this? Or have I got the wrong end of the stick about MVVM?

2) Does presentation logic go in the ViewModel? For instance, in the View I could use Razor to do something like @if (Model.Order.Count > 10)   show an unordered list. Or do I create a boolean field in the ViewModel called something like ShowUnorderedList and populate this value in the service?

3) If I do that kind of presentation logic in the view, how do I unit test the logic in the view?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: Checkout [knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Have done more research, my confusion arose from the fact that I thought that the MVVM pattern was what you called it when you used ViewModels with MVC. However, this is not the case. I am not using MVVM - I am just using ViewModels with ASP.NET MVC.